# Checking if a column has a certain value, then restrict another by a list

Tags: sqlite, boolean-logic, implication

I am wondering if there is any way for me to check if a column has a value, if the value is XXXXX then another column must be in the list of (A,B,C).
something like:

```
CREATE TABLE test (a CHAR(60),b CHAR(60),Check (IF a == 'test' THEN b in ('a','b','c')));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In other words, in `test` rows, `b` must be in the list, while in non-`test` rows, `b` can be anything.

So for the check to succeed, `b` must be in the list, or the row must not be a `test` row:

```
CHECK (a <> 'test' OR b IN ('a', 'b', 'c'))
```

Mathematically, `a → b` is the same as `¬a ∨ b`.